# Read Firebase rules without authentification

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I found a previous question very similar to mine, however the other developper needed to write to Firebase and I don’t, hence this near duplicate question:

I have a very simple database with about 150 documents and the users don’t need to authenticate to use my app. Authentication just don’t make sense for what the app does and users only read the database, they don’t write.

My current rules are read allow only which of course triggers the Firebase rule warning daily.

1) Is there a way to set rules similar to “only requests coming from my app can access it”. Given that the app is linked to firebase one would think it’s possible?

2) If I must use authentification, is there a way that I can do this behind the scenes so that the user is unaware of that? Maybe by using a UUID to identify a user and no password or something like that. I want to avoid showing a log in screen at all cost. Think of it as asking to log in to check gas prices...

** This is an iOS app

Comment: Could [Anonymous authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/anonymous-auth) from Firebase possibly be a solution? You could sign them in as a "guest" without prompting the user for any type of login, and then they count as authenticated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No, it's not possible.
2. You can use [anonymous authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/anonymous-auth) to create a user account without requiring a sign-in.

Comment: I had looked at that and wondered if I could do it without user input. It looks like I can so I'll give that a go. Thanks